# Is Android game bundler ikoid.com a scam site?

Tags: paid-apps

I recently purchased an Android game bundle from https://ikoid.com/.

The purchase was successful (at least they took my money), and I was told I'd receive a link to log in with and collect my purchase.  No such email arrived, and I've had no response from service@ikoid.com.

Has anyone had experience of successful purchases from this site, or similar failures?
Do you know if the site is genuine or a scam?

Update: new purchase successful; the site seems legitimate.

Comment: It doesn't *look* like a scam, but I guess you already thought that. You might contact the developer of one of the games in your bundle directly: they'd know if the site is genuine or not. If you do, please post an answer with the result, to help out other visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We did respond to every e-mail, so it is likely that our e-mails went to your spam folder.

If you still have problems with any purchase please contact us at service@ikoid.com.

Comment: It seems that the original purchase failed (no money was taken) despite receiving a success message. I tried again with a new bundle, and the purchase really was successful, so I'm reassured that this is a genuine site.  I couldn't find any email from service@ikoid, even in my in spam folder, so you may want to double check/update your customer service setup.

Answer (score 1):

I purchased the first bundle and had no problem. The link took a few hours to come by email, but that's all.

EDIT: just purchased this one, got my games added to my account instantaneously (but yes, I already had an account).